# datatables with ajax not loading

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I'm trying to get a table (hopefully with bootstrap) working to allow collapsible rows. I found datatables and been trying to get it working but I can't seem to. Right now, I have a basic table and i'm following the example on the site, but I can't seem to get the ajax data to load. I'm wanting to load the data officially from a db. Below is my code, but for some reason I'm getting "No data available in table". I think I may be missing something.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
      /* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
function format ( d ) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Full name:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.name+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Extension number:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.extn+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Extra info:</td>'+
            '<td>And any further details here (images etc)...</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
    '</table>';
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#myTable').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "test.txt",
        "columns": [
            {
                "className":      'details-control',
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            },
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "salary" }
        ],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']]
    } );

    // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('#myTable tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row( tr );

        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    } );
} );
      </script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#myTable').DataTable();
    });
</script>
<table id="myTable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

AJAX Data Example:
File name: test.txt

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Tiger Nixon",
      "position": "System Architect",
      "salary": "$320,800",
      "start_date": "2011/04/25",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "5421"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Garrett Winters",
      "position": "Accountant",
      "salary": "$170,750",
      "start_date": "2011/07/25",
      "office": "Tokyo",
      "extn": "8422"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "Ashton Cox",
      "position": "Junior Technical Author",
      "salary": "$86,000",
      "start_date": "2009/01/12",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "1562"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "name": "Cedric Kelly",
      "position": "Senior Javascript Developer",
      "salary": "$433,060",
      "start_date": "2012/03/29",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "6224"
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "name": "Airi Satou",
      "position": "Accountant",
      "salary": "$162,700",
      "start_date": "2008/11/28",
      "office": "Tokyo",
      "extn": "5407"
    },
    {
      "id": "6",
      "name": "Brielle Williamson",
      "position": "Integration Specialist",
      "salary": "$372,000",
      "start_date": "2012/12/02",
      "office": "New York",
      "extn": "4804"
    },
    {
      "id": "7",
      "name": "Herrod Chandler",
      "position": "Sales Assistant",
      "salary": "$137,500",
      "start_date": "2012/08/06",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "9608"
    },
    {
      "id": "8",
      "name": "Rhona Davidson",
      "position": "Integration Specialist",
      "salary": "$327,900",
      "start_date": "2010/10/14",
      "office": "Tokyo",
      "extn": "6200"
    },
    {
      "id": "9",
      "name": "Colleen Hurst",
      "position": "Javascript Developer",
      "salary": "$205,500",
      "start_date": "2009/09/15",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "2360"
    },
    {
      "id": "10",
      "name": "Sonya Frost",
      "position": "Software Engineer",
      "salary": "$103,600",
      "start_date": "2008/12/13",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "1667"
    },
    {
      "id": "11",
      "name": "Jena Gaines",
      "position": "Office Manager",
      "salary": "$90,560",
      "start_date": "2008/12/19",
      "office": "London",
      "extn": "3814"
    },
    {
      "id": "12",
      "name": "Quinn Flynn",
      "position": "Support Lead",
      "salary": "$342,000",
      "start_date": "2013/03/03",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "9497"
    },
    {
      "id": "13",
      "name": "Charde Marshall",
      "position": "Regional Director",
      "salary": "$470,600",
      "start_date": "2008/10/16",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "6741"
    },
    {
      "id": "14",
      "name": "Haley Kennedy",
      "position": "Senior Marketing Designer",
      "salary": "$313,500",
      "start_date": "2012/12/18",
      "office": "London",
      "extn": "3597"
    },
    {
      "id": "15",
      "name": "Tatyana Fitzpatrick",
      "position": "Regional Director",
      "salary": "$385,750",
      "start_date": "2010/03/17",
      "office": "London",
      "extn": "1965"
    },
    {
      "id": "16",
      "name": "Michael Silva",
      "position": "Marketing Designer",
      "salary": "$198,500",
      "start_date": "2012/11/27",
      "office": "London",
      "extn": "1581"
    },
    {
      "id": "17",
      "name": "Paul Byrd",
      "position": "Chief Financial Officer (CFO)",
      "salary": "$725,000",
      "start_date": "2010/06/09",
      "office": "New York",
      "extn": "3059"
    },
    {
      "id": "18",
      "name": "Gloria Little",
      "position": "Systems Administrator",
      "salary": "$237,500",
      "start_date": "2009/04/10",
      "office": "New York",
      "extn": "1721"
    },
    {
      "id": "19",
      "name": "Bradley Greer",
      "position": "Software Engineer",
      "salary": "$132,000",
      "start_date": "2012/10/13",
      "office": "London",
      "extn": "2558"
    },
    {
      "id": "20",
      "name": "Dai Rios",
      "position": "Personnel Lead",
      "salary": "$217,500",
      "start_date": "2012/09/26",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "2290"
    },
    {
      "id": "21",
      "name": "Jenette Caldwell",
      "position": "Development Lead",
      "salary": "$345,000",
      "start_date": "2011/09/03",
      "office": "New York",
      "extn": "1937"
    },
    {
      "id": "22",
      "name": "Yuri Berry",
      "position": "Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)",
      "salary": "$675,000",
      "start_date": "2009/06/25",
      "office": "New York",
      "extn": "6154"
    },
    {
      "id": "23",
      "name": "Caesar Vance",
      "position": "Pre-Sales Support",
      "salary": "$106,450",
      "start_date": "2011/12/12",
      "office": "New York",
      "extn": "8330"
    },
    {
      "id": "24",
      "name": "Doris Wilder",
      "position": "Sales Assistant",
      "salary": "$85,600",
      "start_date": "2010/09/20",
      "office": "Sidney",
      "extn": "3023"
    },
    {
      "id": "25",
      "name": "Angelica Ramos",
      "position": "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)",
      "salary": "$1,200,000",
      "start_date": "2009/10/09",
      "office": "London",
      "extn": "5797"
    },
    {
      "id": "26",
      "name": "Gavin Joyce",
      "position": "Developer",
      "salary": "$92,575",
      "start_date": "2010/12/22",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "8822"
    },
    {
      "id": "27",
      "name": "Jennifer Chang",
      "position": "Regional Director",
      "salary": "$357,650",
      "start_date": "2010/11/14",
      "office": "Singapore",
      "extn": "9239"
    },
    {
      "id": "28",
      "name": "Brenden Wagner",
      "position": "Software Engineer",
      "salary": "$206,850",
      "start_date": "2011/06/07",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "1314"
    },
    {
      "id": "29",
      "name": "Fiona Green",
      "position": "Chief Operating Officer (COO)",
      "salary": "$850,000",
      "start_date": "2010/03/11",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "2947"
    },
    {
      "id": "30",
      "name": "Shou Itou",
      "position": "Regional Marketing",
      "salary": "$163,000",
      "start_date": "2011/08/14",
      "office": "Tokyo",
      "extn": "8899"
    },
    {
      "id": "31",
      "name": "Michelle House",
      "position": "Integration Specialist",
      "salary": "$95,400",
      "start_date": "2011/06/02",
      "office": "Sidney",
      "extn": "2769"
    },
    {
      "id": "32",
      "name": "Suki Burks",
      "position": "Developer",
      "salary": "$114,500",
      "start_date": "2009/10/22",
      "office": "London",
      "extn": "6832"
    },
    {
      "id": "33",
      "name": "Prescott Bartlett",
      "position": "Technical Author",
      "salary": "$145,000",
      "start_date": "2011/05/07",
      "office": "London",
      "extn": "3606"
    },
    {
      "id": "34",
      "name": "Gavin Cortez",
      "position": "Team Leader",
      "salary": "$235,500",
      "start_date": "2008/10/26",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "2860"
    },
    {
      "id": "35",
      "name": "Martena Mccray",
      "position": "Post-Sales support",
      "salary": "$324,050",
      "start_date": "2011/03/09",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "8240"
    },
    {
      "id": "36",
      "name": "Unity Butler",
      "position": "Marketing Designer",
      "salary": "$85,675",
      "start_date": "2009/12/09",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "5384"
    },
    {
      "id": "37",
      "name": "Howard Hatfield",
      "position": "Office Manager",
      "salary": "$164,500",
      "start_date": "2008/12/16",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "7031"
    },
    {
      "id": "38",
      "name": "Hope Fuentes",
      "position": "Secretary",
      "salary": "$109,850",
      "start_date": "2010/02/12",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "6318"
    },
    {
      "id": "39",
      "name": "Vivian Harrell",
      "position": "Financial Controller",
      "salary": "$452,500",
      "start_date": "2009/02/14",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "9422"
    },
    {
      "id": "40",
      "name": "Timothy Mooney",
      "position": "Office Manager",
      "salary": "$136,200",
      "start_date": "2008/12/11",
      "office": "London",
      "extn": "7580"
    },
    {
      "id": "41",
      "name": "Jackson Bradshaw",
      "position": "Director",
      "salary": "$645,750",
      "start_date": "2008/09/26",
      "office": "New York",
      "extn": "1042"
    },
    {
      "id": "42",
      "name": "Olivia Liang",
      "position": "Support Engineer",
      "salary": "$234,500",
      "start_date": "2011/02/03",
      "office": "Singapore",
      "extn": "2120"
    },
    {
      "id": "43",
      "name": "Bruno Nash",
      "position": "Software Engineer",
      "salary": "$163,500",
      "start_date": "2011/05/03",
      "office": "London",
      "extn": "6222"
    },
    {
      "id": "44",
      "name": "Sakura Yamamoto",
      "position": "Support Engineer",
      "salary": "$139,575",
      "start_date": "2009/08/19",
      "office": "Tokyo",
      "extn": "9383"
    },
    {
      "id": "45",
      "name": "Thor Walton",
      "position": "Developer",
      "salary": "$98,540",
      "start_date": "2013/08/11",
      "office": "New York",
      "extn": "8327"
    },
    {
      "id": "46",
      "name": "Finn Camacho",
      "position": "Support Engineer",
      "salary": "$87,500",
      "start_date": "2009/07/07",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "2927"
    },
    {
      "id": "47",
      "name": "Serge Baldwin",
      "position": "Data Coordinator",
      "salary": "$138,575",
      "start_date": "2012/04/09",
      "office": "Singapore",
      "extn": "8352"
    },
    {
      "id": "48",
      "name": "Zenaida Frank",
      "position": "Software Engineer",
      "salary": "$125,250",
      "start_date": "2010/01/04",
      "office": "New York",
      "extn": "7439"
    },
    {
      "id": "49",
      "name": "Zorita Serrano",
      "position": "Software Engineer",
      "salary": "$115,000",
      "start_date": "2012/06/01",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "4389"
    },
    {
      "id": "50",
      "name": "Jennifer Acosta",
      "position": "Junior Javascript Developer",
      "salary": "$75,650",
      "start_date": "2013/02/01",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "3431"
    },
    {
      "id": "51",
      "name": "Cara Stevens",
      "position": "Sales Assistant",
      "salary": "$145,600",
      "start_date": "2011/12/06",
      "office": "New York",
      "extn": "3990"
    },
    {
      "id": "52",
      "name": "Hermione Butler",
      "position": "Regional Director",
      "salary": "$356,250",
      "start_date": "2011/03/21",
      "office": "London",
      "extn": "1016"
    },
    {
      "id": "53",
      "name": "Lael Greer",
      "position": "Systems Administrator",
      "salary": "$103,500",
      "start_date": "2009/02/27",
      "office": "London",
      "extn": "6733"
    },
    {
      "id": "54",
      "name": "Jonas Alexander",
      "position": "Developer",
      "salary": "$86,500",
      "start_date": "2010/07/14",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "8196"
    },
    {
      "id": "55",
      "name": "Shad Decker",
      "position": "Regional Director",
      "salary": "$183,000",
      "start_date": "2008/11/13",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "6373"
    },
    {
      "id": "56",
      "name": "Michael Bruce",
      "position": "Javascript Developer",
      "salary": "$183,000",
      "start_date": "2011/06/27",
      "office": "Singapore",
      "extn": "5384"
    },
    {
      "id": "57",
      "name": "Donna Snider",
      "position": "Customer Support",
      "salary": "$112,000",
      "start_date": "2011/01/25",
      "office": "New York",
      "extn": "4226"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you try a simple jQuery Ajax call or an Ajax call using the Datatables Ajax callback function and show the result? Is it an error or just an empty response?

Comment: I'm not familiar with AJAX really to know how to do so. Right now, no database is in the loop. Its just a text file. Updating the question with the example data

Comment: https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html this is the example i'm trying to follow

Comment: Instead of  `"ajax": "test.txt"` try 

`$.ajax({
  url: "test.txt",
  context: document.body,
  success: function(response){console.debug(response);},
  error: function(xhr, status){console.debug(status);}
})`

 Then open up your browsers developer tools (F12 on Chrome and Firefox) click on "console" and post what gets printed there.

Comment: @Yserbius Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string

Comment: Line 29...right below where I put what you wanted me to.

Comment: Go back to your original code, and run it again but this time open up the "Network" tab on your development tools and see if there's a listing for "test.txt". That means that your browser was getting data from there.

Comment: Nope, no test.txt. I see index.html and everything else that was called though

Comment: Try this code on its own (just stick it in the `ready` function) and tell me if the console and network tabs say anything

`$.ajax({ url: "test.txt", context: document.body, success: function(response){console.debug(response);}, error: function(xhr, status){console.debug(status);} })`

Comment: you mean just a new html page?

Comment: Yeah. same thing, just in the `ready` function put my code and nothing else.

Comment: I had to put an extra }) and then I got Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: This is the whole page now: <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({ url: "test.txt", context: document.body, success: function(response){console.debug(response);}, error: function(xhr, status){console.debug(status);} })
  })
   </script>

Comment: You didn't include `jquery` in the script

`<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
`

Also, you should check out jsfiddle.net, it's a javascript sandbox that lets you try out JS code.

Comment: jquery-1.7.1.min.js:4 Failed to load file:///C:/test.txt: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: reading online, it means I need a webserver...moving it now and testing.

Comment: Yeesh. There's your problem. Browsers don't like requests for data to local file systems. The only way to fix this is to run a simple web server, like WAMP Server, that has both your HTML and test.txt files on it. Or you could just forgoe AJAX and stick all the data at the beginning of your HTML file. So copy and past the whole test.txt file to the first line of your javascript code and add something like `var myData = data: [ ....(rest of the file)`. Then instead of `ajax: 'test.txt'` just use `data: myData.data`.

Comment: I put everything on the webserver. For the test file where you were instructing to debug, test.txt showed under network. For my original code, it did not.

Comment: I suggest you play around with JQuery and Ajax calls so you can be comfortable with the terminology and code. That way it will be easier for you to debug on your own.

Comment: ok, thanks for your help

Comment: @yusof why are you initializing datatable two times in `document.ready`? As per my understanding, this is causing the `empty datatable` because in first initialization, you are specifying datasource i.e. `test.txt` while in second  initialization, you are not specifying any options for datatable `$(document).ready(function(){ $('#myTable').DataTable(); });`

Comment: Was following the example on the site. I removed the second document.ready and it's still not pulling the data or calling that file.